# Unable to pick a few elements after migrating

Tags: ee2, php, javascript

I have recently cloned my ExpressionEngine CMS (2.3) website to a new VPS with Plesk as its control panel.

For cloning, I copied all my files and imported the database from existing website into the new VPS.

When I preview the website or change my hosts file to view the website from my VPS, I see that a few elements are not getting picked (Screenshot attached).

So, I think it is just a matter of setting the correct relative/absolute paths in the preferences, but after trying many options, it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know where to go from here? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen to it that the paths you're associating templates with are:

1. the correct path? Maybe templates have moved.
2. the path has the correct permissions? If files are there but not readable, this is the same result

Comment: Looks like your server path to the template directory has changed. Which is to be expected when moving to a plesk server

Comment: Yes, I spotted it straightaway when I explored a few preferences pages. It was indeed the template folder that needed its path changed. Thank you Holland and Jelle for your replies! :)